# Shortcut to Checking a String in a While Loop for Java?

Tags: java, string, loops, while-loop, shortcut

I'm completely new to Java programming. I'm wondering if there's a shortcut to checking an input String with **many** preset possibilities. As an example, I'm trying to check to see if the input matches up to specific Strings, and if it doesn't, I want it to go through a while loop until the spelling errors made by the user have been corrected.

But instead of writing

```
!string.equalsIgnoreCase("badstring")) && !string.equalsIgnoreCase("badstring2")) &&
!string.equalsIgnoreCase("badstring3")) && ...
```

etc. for, say, 40 different string possibilities, is there an easier way to write it?

Or do I just need to write

```
!__.equalsIgnoreCase("__") && ...
```

over and over?

Answer (score 3):

It's best to use Java's new aggregate operations feature for your problem. Here's how you could do it:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class TestStrings {
    public static void main(String... args) {
        String tester = "Some string";
        ArrayList<String> badStrings = new ArrayList<>(1),
        result = new ArrayList<>(0);

        badStrings.add("Bad string 1");
        badStrings.add("Some string");
        // add more strings;

        // filter out good strings
        badStrings.stream().filter((s) -> {
            // the filter
            return tester.equals(s);
        }).forEach((s) -> {
            // fill the result list with the good strings
            result.add(s);
        });

        System.out.println(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could store your *bad strings* in a Collection, and check your input by looping through the collection.

```
List<String> badStringList = new ArrayList<>();
badStringList.add("badString 1");
badStringList.add("badString 2");
badStringList.add("badString 3");
 ...
badStringList.add("badString N");

for (String badString : badStringList){
    if (!inputString.equalsIgnoreCase(badString))) {
        doSomething();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of checking what you dont want check what you want, for e.g. in below code i want the word "Hello" as input so i'm checking only "Hello".
Please elaborate if something else is expected.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class StringEquals {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    while(true){
        Scanner kbd=new Scanner(System.in);
        String input=kbd.nextLine();
        if(input.equalsIgnoreCase("Hello")){
        System.out.println("String matched");
        System.out.println("Please try again");
        break;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Comment: It's not about what I want or don't want; either way, if I want to check if I want or don't want 40 items, I'd still have to type out "input.equalsIgnoreCase("hello")&&" etcetera 40 times. I was just wondering if there's a shortcut I can use where, say, I only use "input.equalsIgnoreCase("hello1","hello2","hello3")" and so on; something like that where I can shorten up the command and simply list all of the options I want to check. Hopefully that makes more sense.

Comment: So why don't you use input.contains("Hello");

Comment: I've never seen that structure before (as said, I'm brand new to Java). What's that form called?